# Dynamically adjusting two outside columns to the variable width of the center column

Tags: html, css

I would consider myself to be an intermediate/advanced CSS/HTML coder but I'm stumped on how to do the following scenario.. I'm starting to think it is impossible but I really want to believe it is..

Let's say the wrapper width is 1000px.

Within it is three columns. The two outside columns are the same width, this width is decided by the center column. The center column is the only one with content, just one line of text with 30px of padding on either side. So if the line of content is 100px with padding, than the other two columns would be (1000-100)/2 each..

Is there a dynamic way to have the two outside columns adjust to the varying width of the center column that is defined by its varying contents, one line of text?

Graphic of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMuBP.png]

Comment: hmm.. I just came up with a way of doing it with two divs, one inside the other.. probably even a little neater than the three column idea.. in any case, is it possible with the three columns?

Comment: Is this an actual programming problem you're facing? If so, consider rephrasing your question as such, as well as showing us anything you may have tried (e.g. do you have some base markup for us to work with?). We generally prefer questions about practical problems to questions about coding puzzles.

Comment: I believe this article covers what you're looking for: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/

Comment: Haven't given it much of a thought but I think this task is better suited for JavaScript. With pure CSS this might not be possible.

Comment: I think it's a practical problem that happens to be somewhat of a puzzle to answer. Not quite David, thanks though. I think you're right Ali, I've tried a lot, Js would be well suited to handle this. However my two div solution will do fine for now, I'll post the markup for it shortly.

Comment: So something maybe similar to this fiddle, but with a center div that does not have a fixed width? http://jsfiddle.net/fTPjZ/2/

Comment: Yea that's the problem, the center div needs to be dynamic width-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good 'ole tables to the rescue:

http://jsfiddle.net/hgwdT/

Actually I think tables are the devil, but this works as you described. And so here it is using `display: table-cell` on the child divs, so it is functionally the same using nicer markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/XXXdB/

The center element can indeed have a dynamic width; to prevent the content from being squished, I simply added a `white-space: nowrap` to the `p` containing the text.

I also confirmed that this solution works in IE8 and FF, in addition to Chrome.

Comment: I can't say I'm surprised.. I think deep down I thought there was some funny way a table could do it. I implemented the table way and it works, was going to replace with divs but you beat me too it, thanks!

Comment: I think tables are there for when we need something to stay in a row even when the widths don't add up (like how here we have 50% + 50% + dynamic center = 100%), or when we need content dynamically centered vertically, and don't want to use Javascript. Otherwise I know I'd be done with them completely.

Comment: Or, you know, for displaying tabular content I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The very closest I could come up with was to use display: table; and table-cell. This creates the dynamic effect you're looking for, but I don't think you can get your desired effect without setting an explicit width to the center element.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        center
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrap
{
    width: 1000px;
    display: table;
}

#wrap div
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: auto;
}

#center
{
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You can [check out my attempt here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/Ds6Nm/), it has some buttons for you to see the different states, width on/off and add text etc. (the jQuery has nothing to do with the solution)

I think this is as close as you're going to get with pure CSS.

Comment: You're kidding? Tables beat a well structured div based layout? I give up on SO.

Comment: I hate to say it but I think even in this case, yes. Table hating is sooo 2005, as long as your not using tables as your wrapper or nesting tables inside tables inside tables.. using a table here and there is surely justified in this day and age when everyone uses a reset anyways. Besides, I would have replaced the table markup with div according, but jblasco was kind of enough to do it for me. Don't fret, you certainly aided in steering us down the right path!

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Well my thought was that a table could do it, and I wanted to make sure it could before transferring the styles to divs, so I posted a partial solution first to show it works, and then finished the rest using the nicer markup we all love.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did in the first place, but good solution with the 50% on each side, I was actually about to implment that when I saw your answer. Tables are no good for this situation though :)

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Well, I kind of think of using `display: table-cell`, etc, as using tables without technically using tables; the CSS property wouldn't be there without them. So they kind of do fit the situation, heh.

Comment: Haha, yes. But obviously a nice div layout is far better than a table structure :) Good job.

Answer (score 1):

This not the most elegant solution, but it works. I wanted to go the pure CSS route, but couldn't figure it out. Nice work, jblasco and Kyle Sevenoaks, on figuring that out!

Here is my [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackrugile/DBs5J/). If you don't mind using a little JavaScript though (utilizing jQuery in my example):

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div id="middle">One line of text.</div>
    <div class="side"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;    
}

#wrapper div {
    float: left;   
    height: 300px;
}

.side {
    background: #ddd;   
}

#middle {
    background: #eee;  
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
var adjustSize = function(){
    // Declare vars
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
        middle = $('#middle'),
        totalWidth = wrapper.width(),
        middleWidth = middle.width(),
        middleOuterWidth = middle.outerWidth(),
        remainingWidth = totalWidth - middleOuterWidth,
        sideWidth;

    if(remainingWidth % 2 === 0){
        // Remaining width is even, divide by two
        sideWidth = remainingWidth/2;
    } else {
        // Remaining width is odd, add 1 to middle to prevent a half pixel
        middle.width(middleWidth+1);
        sideWidth = (remainingWidth-1)/2;  
    }

    // Adjust the side width
    $('.side').width(sideWidth);
}
```