# Three column layout - middle one dynamic width, other two fill up the rest of the container and center the middle one

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to display a centered message in a "bubble", with two decorative lines flanking it. Something like this:

```
  -----------  Message  -----------
```

Message can be of dynamic width and isn't controlled by me. If it reaches a maximum width, it should move onto a new line. If it's not as wide as that maximum width, the "bubble" should shrink to its size. The width of the whole container that fits the three columns is known.

My research lead me to believe that using display:table is the best solution to a problem like this, especially since I want to vertically align the decorative lines. I've found a ton of related similar questions but none that exactly get it. [This one is the closest(jblasco's solution), but it doesn't work - as soon as you add a maximum width it stops working as desired.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530419/dynamically-adjusting-two-outside-columns-to-the-variable-width-of-the-center-co)

I need to support back to IE8, Chrome, and Safari. I can use javascript to do it, and I suspect that's what I'll end up doing here, but I would  prefer to avoid any visible changes to content that has already been rendered, so a pure CSS solution would be preferable.

[Here's a JSFiddle showing what I've come up with.](http://jsfiddle.net/alexpelan/fta9obaa/) The "Short Message" should not have that whitespace to the right, and any solution should not modify how the "Long message" is displayed.

Comment: the markup that you have on youre fiddle, can it be changed, or has to stay exactly how its set atm?(I believe you can accomplish the same thing with less markup you currently have) thanks!

Comment: @Crispy-George Yes, I can change the markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah pesky IE8 support .... I was about to fire with flexbox all over, but since you need that to work on IE8, some other method must be used.

Table trick won't really cut it, max-width/min-width issues, that bubble won't really expand/shrink, although might be useful if you want to change your bubble to fixed width.

I believe :pseudo elements are supported in IE8, so why not use those to achieve what you're looking for. However this method has its  downfalls: you'll need to mask out the edges of the lines with some background, in this case I used #fff, or white background to mask em.

So what I did was the following:

- wrap everything related to the bubble, in a **container**, I used `.bubble-message-wrap`
- the **content** itself wrap it in a class, say `.bubble-message-entry`
- set the **container** to relative positioned & text-align center
- use a `:before` class from the **container** to position absolute, 50% from the top, 1px height and your desired background: this is going to act like the '2 lines' required
- now the **content** itself set it to display inline block so it would be sent to the middle of the **container**, and use some max-width on it to where you need it to expand
- since your **content** neeeds to have that border around it, we'll need to use here both `:before` & `:after` elements from it
- set the **content** to position relative, and the pseudo elements from above, to absolute positioned, so theyll be bound to their parent and not to the **container**
- set the background to white color, and position one to the left and one to the right, so theyll act like a mask over the line, to give the impression of some space between the lines and the bubble itself
- and thats about it.

This should work out properly in IE8, not sure about border-radius, but the shrinking/expanding stuff should work.

Check out the **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ekb1jqrv/1/)** or the snippet bellow and hope this helps you

```css
/*new stuff*/

.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.bubble-message-wrap {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*the line*/

.bubble-message-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  /*your desired color for the line*/
}
.bubble-message-entry {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 60%;
  /*the width of the bubble that it will reach untill it will break to the next line*/
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #fff;
  /*so it wont show the line behind it*/
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666666;
  border: 1px #666666 solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/*mask out the edges of the bubble*/

.bubble-message-entry:before,
.bubble-message-entry:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
}
/*bellow are the mask for the line, you can play around,
width left/right props depending on how much space you need
between the edges of the bubble and the lines*/

/*the mask on the left*/

.bubble-message-entry:before {
  left: -20px;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
/*the mask on the right*/

.bubble-message-entry:after {
  left: 100%;
  right: -20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pseudo elements and mask the line</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class='bubble-message-wrap'>
    <div class='bubble-message-entry'>
      This one is really short, no problems here, move on
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='bubble-message-wrap'>
    <div class='bubble-message-entry'>
      This one is kinda long, but not really too long so we wont spoil it
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='bubble-message-wrap'>
    <div class='bubble-message-entry'>
      This one is really long, you could write a novel maybe here, and still have some room for some funky text wrapping on the next line, right?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='bubble-message-wrap'>
    <div class='bubble-message-entry'>
      Now you went too far, this bubble seem to expand nonetheless, and still wrap line after line, after line ... Notice that the left and right lines stay in the middle? Now thats some funky stuff, eh?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pseudo elements are supported in IE8, so this looks great. I initially tried to get this working with some pseudo elements but wasn't able to get too far on it. And yes, flexbox would probably be a better solution for anyone that didn't have to support IE8. Thanks!

Comment: @alexpelan no problem-o, glad to help out! Cheerio!

Answer (score 0):

here is my approach 
http://jsfiddle.net/69q3L6hz/3/

```
<div class="main">
<div class="text">
MAIN MESSAGES
</div>
```

css

```
.main {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block; // inline-block will reside to fit child content
    vertical-align: middle;  // this will center the before/after content
    max-width: 500px; // the width will be dynamic, if with more than max width, it will force new line
}
.main:before {
    content: "-->"    
}
.main:after {
    content: "<--"   
}
```

I think this is what you are after.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Putting text into the "main" div causes the left and right divs to shift downwards, and the yellow div doesn't shrink to the size of that text.

Comment: Sorry, I jump too quick to know what you are asking, I will make changes let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2hamed/xjttee66/).

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="text">A really long text to have</div>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    background:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}
.line{
    border-top:1px solid #333;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%
}
.text{
    margin:5px 15px;
    background:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Close but not quite there - the two examples need to be the same width. Using z-index to put the line behind the text is a good idea, but I can't horizontally center the text: http://jsfiddle.net/alexpelan/nfamtc4k/